# Image Picker in SKScene

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I'm working on a game and I would like to choose the background image of the game scene from the Camera Roll.

I have all the necessary code to import an imageView from the Camera Roll in the ViewController.m, but it doesn't work in the Game SKScene.

I tried to import in the SKScene the ImageView you pick from the ImagePicker and than set it as background Image, but the application crashes when I build it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please try to focus on a specific question. Also, try to only include relevant code

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do here, however do you want to get a picture from camera roll and make it the background?

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UINavigationControllerDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate> {

IBOutlet UIImageView *ImageView;
UIImagePickerController *picker;
UIImage *image;
}

//.m file

-(IBAction)TakePhoto:(id)sender {
picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self; 
[picker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

//Saving the image
NSString *imgName= @"imgname.png"; 
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setValue:imgName forKey:@"imageName"];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,     NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

[BackGround setImage:image]; //Setting the background to the image

if (image.size.width < image.size.height) {
BackGround.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill; //If the image too big make it fit
BackGround.clipsToBounds = YES;

//Re-save the image
NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:imgName];
UIImage *imageSave = image; // imageView is my image from camera
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageSave);
[imageData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:NO];
}
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}

-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}



 //Collect the image, pass it between files/view controllers

NSString *imgName= [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"imageName"];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",documentsDir,imgName];
[BackGround setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath]];
```